# fail to send ajax request with GET

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="untitled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/local/path/to/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myRequest;
  var serverAddress="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>?thread_id="+4;

  function doWork()
  {
      myRequest=createXmlHttpRequestObject();
      if(myRequest!=null)
      {
         try
         {
           myRequest.open("GET",serverAddress,true);
          myRequest.onreadystatechange=display;
           myRequest.send(null);
         }
         catch(e)
         {
             alert("Send failed");
         }
      }
  }


  function display()
  { 
      if(myRequest.readyState ==4)
      {
          if(myRequest.status==200)
          {


                  getData();

          }
      }
      else
      {

      }

  }

  function getData()
  {

  }

</script>
</head>

<body>


<?php 

  if( isset($_GET["thread_id"]) )
  { 
       echo 'Thread_id: '.$_GET["thread_id"];
  }


  /*     $dom=new DOMDocument();
     $response=$dom->createElement('response');
     $dom->appendChild($response);
     $responseText=$dom->createTextNode('1dd');
     $response->appendChild($responseText);
     $xmlString=$dom->saveXML();
     echo $xmlString;*/


?>




<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<form action="" method="get">

<table width="200" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    Name:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
    Password:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="password" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">  
    <input name="post" type="button" value="post"  onclick="doWork()"/>
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>

</form>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div align="center" id="myDiv2"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

the Thread_id never gets printed.. no thread_id is set, even though, I did put it as a url parameter before sending it in the javascript code:

```
 **if( isset($_GET["thread_id"]) )


 { 
       echo 'Thread_id: '.$_GET["thread_id"];
  **}**
```

**Why isnt the trhead_id echoed out, when I click the button (when the xmlhttpRequest is being obtained?!?)****

```
Source:http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-get-php
I want to to get $_Get..The question is whether I can send a request to my own page or I have to send a request with the Get parameters to another page...to make an echo!??!
    <?php
    // if data are received via GET, with index of 'test'
    if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
        $str = $_GET['test'];             // get data
        echo "The string '<i>".$str."</i>' contains ". strlen($str). ' characters and '. str_word_count($str, 0). ' words.';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why not use an AJAX library? Have you checked it is being fired correctly using the browser developer tools?

Comment: Can you show us the display function?

Comment: are you sure you $_GET['thread_id'] is set? you say it works, but did you test this?

Comment: yeah, I did,, it is set to 0..but even with 33, it doesnt work

Comment: I will show you all my code..test it yoruself

Comment: So your AJAX is submitting sending a request to itself? It won't print the response because it is going to be sent in the response text.

Comment: I dont want to print the response I want to print this: echo 'Thread_id: '.$_GET["thread_id"];... why doesnt the thread_id set.. I do set it above: var serverAddress="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>?thread_id="+4;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns what I expected it to return. In the console it returns the whole page. I would suggest you read up on XHR and AJAX.

Probably a good place to start http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="untitled.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/local/path/to/firebug-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myRequest;
  var serverAddress="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>?thread_id="+4;

  function doWork()
  {
      myRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
      if(myRequest!=null)
      {
         try
         {
           myRequest.open("GET",serverAddress,true);
          myRequest.onreadystatechange=display;
           myRequest.send(null);
         }
         catch(e)
         {
             alert("Send failed");
         }
      }
  }


  function display()
  { 
      if(myRequest.readyState ==4)
      {
          if(myRequest.status==200)
          {

                console.debug(myRequest.responseText);
                  getData();

          }
      }
      else
      {

      }

  }

  function getData()
  {

  }

</script>
</head>

<body>


<?php 

  if( isset($_GET["thread_id"]) )
  { 
       echo 'Thread_id: '.$_GET["thread_id"];
  }


  /*     $dom=new DOMDocument();
     $response=$dom->createElement('response');
     $dom->appendChild($response);
     $responseText=$dom->createTextNode('1dd');
     $response->appendChild($responseText);
     $xmlString=$dom->saveXML();
     echo $xmlString;*/


?>




<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<form action="" method="get">

<table width="200" border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    Name:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>
    Password:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name="password" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">  
    <input name="post" type="button" value="post"  onclick="doWork()"/>
    </td>


  </tr>
</table>

</form>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div align="center" id="myDiv2"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont want it to return the whole page. I know it returns the whole page if I do myRequest.responseText..   I want the php to echo out what is inside the get statement......when I click the button.. and thanks for the reading, I think I will pass

Comment: That is not how AJAX works. It will not just reload the page you are on. The AJAX will have the text that is output from the page you requested. The whole point of AJAX is not to reload the whole page, but just portions. It will not re-parse the PHP on the page sending the request. Honestly I think you need to read about AJAX, as I believe that you don't have a clear understanding of how it works.

Comment: I do understand how it works, sorry if I have to make you understand.. but even in this example on this page: http://www.coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-get-php ... they use the same way of coding..if (isset($_GET['test']))... see..server side checks for get.. so if you want to prove me wrong, could you also prove the example in the link as wrong..?

Comment: Eagle. you seem to be clueless.. who was talking about parsing the page from the beginning?..

Comment: The page parses fine, and server returns the thread id in the RESPONSETEXT along with ALL of the other HTML. If you want it to just return the   

if( isset($_GET["thread_id"]) )
  { 
       echo 'Thread_id: '.$_GET["thread_id"];
  }

Then you either need to create a separate page with just that call on it and make the request to that, or wrap your HTML in an if stmt that doesn't output the html if a thread is present. You then have to take the data, and use something like getElementById to add it to the page. It will not re-run the PHP and output what you are expecting.

Comment: I understand what you want, but your implementation is flawed and I have suggested that you read up on how to use AJAX. I think if you took 20 minutes and read through the link I gave you, you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: I think I cant post to my own page, but I have to post the ajax request to another file (e.g. php, html, or xml) for it to work..I start to undestand now